# How early does a hashable type need to become immutable?

Tags: python, hashing

Suppose I have a class that looks vaguely like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    _value = None  # XXX: see below

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        """The value of this Foo."""
        return self._value

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(self) is type(other) and self.value == other.value
```

(I know the `_value = None` line is wrong; in my actual code, `_value` is a data descriptor with a default value.  It never raises `AttributeError` even if it hasn't been set yet, and I'm just trying to emulate that behavior in as few lines of code as possible.  I could rip the behavior out, but it would significantly complicate things in other areas of my codebase.)

Have I violated the rules?  Should I be setting `_value` in `Foo.__new__()` instead?  Clearly it needs to be set somewhere; there will be a point in time at which the `hash()` of our instance changes.  When should that happen, exactly?

If there is *not* anything wrong with the above code, then why is the following code wrong?  Logically, this combination is illegal, but I'm not sure which class has broken the rules:

```
bar = set()

class Baz(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bar.add(self)
        super(Baz, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # play nice with MI

class Qux(Baz, Foo):
    pass

assert Qux('quuux') in bar  # assertion fires because the hash() changed
```

Comment: `there will be a point in time at which the hash() of our instance changes. When should that happen, exactly?` -- Before the rest of your program has a chance to read the hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say `Baz` has broken the rules. By using `self` as hashable before even invoking other `__init__` methods in the MRO, it assumes that those methods do nothing to influence the hash. That is a wrong assumption. Although technically it is safer to construct immutable classes so that `__new__` sets up all state and makes it completely, utterly, immutable (like `tuple` and `namedtuple`), this is often very clunky and unnecessary.

Setting some private variables that are read-only for the outside world and never mutated in any methods (other than `__init__` where they are first set) is a **perfectly valid and common way** to implement immutable classes.

This ties into a more general point: Doing *anything* at all with an object while it's still being initialized is very risky and need to be thought out very well. Many invariants may be violated before `__init__` has finished, so most code can't meaningfully interact with a partially-initialized object. Luckily, a sane `__new__` implementation takes care that the new object is first passed to `__init__` (and, of course, any code that `__init__` invokes itself — which, again, needs to be carefully chosen).

Answer (score 1):

The instance should be immutable at the moment it is used as a key in a dict. Before that, it can mutate. But *preferably* it should be incapable of mutation after the moment of construction, just to avoid programming errors.

The builder pattern fits this well: the final `.build()` step returns an immutable object. You can additionally prevent inadvertent attribute modification by setting instance's `__setattr__` to something raising an exception.

Unfortunately, you did not provide a minimal runnable example of the problem in the second code fragment. Next time [please do](http://sscce.org/). I only can suspect that somewhere in the real problematic code you conflate `self` of the original object with something else. (The idea of updating a global hash table from a constructor does not strike me as a particularly elegant one, though [memoizing decorators](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578231-probably-the-fastest-memoization-decorator-in-the-/) usually do this reliably.)

Comment: The code *is* runnable, if you concatenate the two snippets and replace the bare `value` in `Baz.__init__` with any concrete value.

Comment: Fixed, see question.  My actual codebase only has the `Foo` stuff; it lacks `Baz` and `Qux` entirely.  I'm just trying to code defensively in case someone else writes them.